# How do I move my local Git repository to a remote Git repository

Tags: git

I have various Git projects that are on my local machine. I have a server that I would like to use as my remote Git  Repository. How do I move my local Git Repositories (Projects) to my server while keeping the history intact?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks for all the great answers. The response I choose makes sense to my limited GIT knowledge.

EDIT #2:
I noticed my original answer selection did not copy my tags. `git push --mirror <path>` does copy tags.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

On your server create the git repositories as bare repository

```
git init --bare repo.git
```

then, push the commits of your local repository

```
git push --mirror ssh://yourserver/~/repo.git
```

Comment: If I do that, will anybody will be able to clone my repo? (if they know the adress)

Comment: @sliders_alpha: if they have SSH access to your server and the repository has proper permissions, then yes.

Comment: There is so much shit about this. Thanks for the best and easies way!

Comment: This does't work for me at all or else I'm mis-understanding the question. `git init --bare repo.git` makes a folder called `repo.git` with git files inside. Why would I want that? I'd think I'd want a folder called "repo" with a ".git" folder inside like the 100+ repos I've used in the past. If I do `git init --bare repo/.git` I get "repo" with a ".git". But then I do the push. On the server I get an unusable repo with lots of `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` How is this the correct answer?

Comment: @gman: It is a bare repository (only the internal database). You can use `git push` and `git fetch` to synchronize your repositories (as mentioned in my answer). To get the files, you'd use `git clone` in a different directory or on a different machine. That's the very basic concept of Git's distributed nature.

Comment: I get that. I want the remote's repository to be effectively be clone, not just the internal db.

Comment: @gman: then either create a clone from the remote repository (recommended), or create a non-bare repository (simply leave out the `--bare`). Pushing into non-bare repositories is not recommended, and pushing to the currently checked out branch is usually prohibited unless enabled by a config option.

Comment: Who said anything about a remote repository? I have a local repo. I want a clone of it remotely. I have ssh access to remote. remote does not have ssh access to local. There is no 3rd machine to coordinate between. But yea, apparently to do this I have to setup config options, or do a slow scp, or .tar.gz, or git bundle. I'd have thought this was a common situtation but I guess not (｀_´)ゞ

Comment: @gman: what stops you from cloning the repository on the remote server (from the remote server)? First do a `git init --bare`, then push to the repo, ssh into the server, `git clone /path/to/bare/repo.git localclone`

Comment: Having a data quota on the remote server and needing double the space to have both the pushed repo and the clone. It seems silly to have to have 2 copies of the data. That's like one step from just .tar.gz-ing my local folder , uploading that and extracting it.

Comment: @gman: then create a non-bare repository on the server. Nobody is prohibiting you from doing it. Or stay with tar/scp/rsync – the end result should be pretty much the same. My answer solely focuses on the Git way

Comment: I'm going based on my understanding of the question. Maybe it's the wording. If I have something local and I want to move it to remote I expect it work the same on remote. But following your steps remote is not the same as local. Local has a checkout, remote does not, ... maybe it's the word "repository" that's got me confused.

Comment: The answer is missing the step that to have a usable clone you have to clone the bare repository on the remote machine.

Comment: @weberjn no cloning is required, you are already pushing everything into the remote

Answer (score 72):

First, create a git repo on your server

```
git init --bare /path/to/repo
```

Then add the remote repo to your local one (ssh:// or https://)

```
git remote add origin ssh://server/path/to/repo
```

And, push files/commits

```
git push origin master
```

And finally, push tags

```
git push origin --tags
```

Comment: I prefer this one because --mirror option (from git help:) "Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end."

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The remote repo gets all kinds of `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` errors if I try to do anything with it

Comment: This works well for me, I added the line for pushing tags as well. Note: the ssh:// protocol can also be https://.

Comment: Thanks for this, and upvoted. :) I was wondering if you'd be up to improving this answer by explaining that "origin" can be any name, but typically that's the one that's used. (I'm in a situation where I'm pulling from an origin, modifying in a local repo, and pushing to a different repo entirely.)

Comment: This example is the best but it leaves the original local repo not tracking the new remote bare repo... You can fix that with `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`

Answer (score 13):

There is a good tutorial on [Ralf Wernders blog](http://rwehner.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/a-simple-way-to-create-git-repository-on-a-server-machine-connecting-via-ssh/). Assuming you know how to create a repository on the server, or that has already been done:

```
git remote add <remote> <url>
```

To add a remote to your local repository. `<remote>` is the name of the remote (often "origin"). `<url>` is the url to your repository with write access (like git@...)

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

To move the commits over to the origin. `<branch>` is the branch you're pushing (often "master").

Comment: this question is not about github. It's about git

Comment: if you want to push and pull you can add
git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 4):

Create a git repository on the server (you can use gitolite/gitosis or just a normal user account + pubkey ssh auth), add the server to your local git repository using

```
git remote add name url
```

and use `git push -u name master` (`-u` marks the current branch as tracking so you can just `git pull` instead `git pull name master`).

On the server side (debian based system):

```
adduser --system --home /home/git --bash /bin/bash git
su - git
mkdir .ssh
cat yourkey.pub > .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, create a new bare repository for each local repository using

```
mkdir projectName
cd projectName
git init --bare
```

After that, the url would be `git@yourserver:projectName`.

Comment: it is asking for password so what password i have to use?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a stand-alone local working tree repository (a folder with a ".git" folder inside) that you want to add a remote to:

1. Create a new empty repository in the remote.
2. In the local repository, set the new remote as the origin:

   > cd localrepo
   >
   > git remote add origin REMOTEURL   #(verify with git remote -v)
3. Push all local branches to the remote, and set each local branch to track the corresponding remote branch:

   > git push --all --set-upstream origin  #(verify with git branch -vv)
4. Push all local tags to the remote:

   > git push --tags origin

At this point the local repository will act just like it had been cloned from the remote.

---

If you have a bare local repository (a folder with a name ending in .git) that you just want to copy to a remote:

1. Create a new empty repository in the remote.
2. In the local repository, push all of its branches to the remote

   > cd localrepo.git
   >
   > git push --all REMOTEURL
3. Push all local tags to the remote:

   > git push --tags REMOTEURL

Answer (score 3):

If you want a normal (eg: not bare) repository, just copy it.  There is nothing special that needs to be done.

If you want to use a bare repository on the server, just initialize it on the server, add it as a remote on the "local" copy, then push to it.  (`git push --mirror` will get everything through.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. on remote, `mkdir somefolder; cd somefolder; git  init`. On local `git push --mirror ssh://remote/somefolder`. Result `remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is "backwards", but I've always done

```
git clone --bare localrepo localrepo.git
scp -r localrepo.git remoteserver:/pathTo
mv localrepo localrepo-prev
git clone remoteserver:/pathTo/localrepo
```

prove out the new repo is fine, with git status/log etc to make me feel better

move any files not under version control from -prev to the new localrepo

```
rm -rf localrepo.git localrepo-prev
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a local repo with commit logs. I wanted to add it a a new github remote repository with all the commit logs preserved. Here is how:

1. create the remote repo on the github. And get the the repo URL from the "Clone or Download" green button, such as  https://github.com/mhisoft/eVault.git
2. If the local repo was attached to an old orgin. remove it first

   > git remote remove origin
3. Add the existing repository from the command line

   > git remote add origin https://github.com/mhisoft/eVault.git
   >
   > git push -u origin master

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the first two most upvoted answers. But it throws all sort of errors. Maybe because things have been updated in the 'git'.
This is what I did.
If you have tried any other methods, delete the '.git' folder by 'rm -rf ./.git' also If you have created a remote repo delete it to do a fresh start.

#. In your local repo initiate the git.

`git init`

#. Add the file (you can create a .gitignore file if you want to ignore certain file or file type or folders, this is optional).

```
git add .
```

#. make the first commit

```
git commit -m "First commit"
```

#. Now create an **empty** repository in bitbucket/github
log in to the bitbucket/github and create a new repository with no readme or .gitignore. If there is any file tnere or commit, it will create problem. There are other procedures for that.

[In BitBucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYyP.jpg)

[In Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8hIo.png)

#. Add this repository in the BitBucket/Github as 'remote' for the local repository. Go to the root of the local repository directory.

```
git remote add origin Remote_URL_Of_the_Repo
```

#. The Remote_URL looks like https://UserName@bitbucket.org/UserName/RepositoryName.git

#. Push the local files to the remote repository

```
git push origin master
```

#. Once complete you will see the local files, master branch, commits in the remote.