# How to push local repository to remote in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository

I have a project in visual studio. I want to create remote repository for it and push it there. Is it possible to do all of that in visual studio or is my only option to use git in command line, follow the answer of [How do I move my local Git repository to a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978650/how-do-i-move-my-local-git-repository-to-a-remote-git-repository) and clone my remote repo in IDE?

I have added local repository to the project in Visual Studio and created remote repository. However when i try to push local to remote I receive the following outgoing commits message: The current branch does not track a remote branch. Push your changes to a new branch on the origin remote and set the upstream branch.

Comment: Check this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitworkflow?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a repository manually on the remote server. Usually you can do that using a web interface (like GitHub, BitBucket, etc). Once you have your repository created, you need an initial commit. For this part, you have 2 options:

1. Create the initial commit using that same web interface and then clone the repository to your local machine and you're done: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver067/clone-a-repository-979426617.html
2. Initialize the new repository on your local machine, in the project folder, push it to the remote repository and you're done: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html

Doing this from Visual Studio is possible through the [Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/work-team-explorer?view=azure-devops) tool window. First, use `Manage Connections` to create/initialize/clone the repository locally and then use `Changes` and `Sync` buttons to update your commits and push/pull changes to the remote repository.

Comment: I have copied my project to mapped drive and added git to it from Visual Studio (it appears as local repository in VS). Then I cloned this to my local drive. When I try to push a commit to repository on mapped drive I get the following error: Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

Comment: On the other hand when i try to push from local repository to newly created repository on mapped drive i get the following error: failed to push some refs to 'repo_path’.

Comment: Check the permissions on the mapped drive. It seems like you don't have write permissions on it.